# Xamarin.Forms - migrating from MVVMCross 4 to 5 - MvxFormsApp doesn't exist?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

In MVVMCross's own guide to migrating from 4 to 5 they say this method should be as follows in the iOS Setup.cs class:

```
protected override IMvxIosViewPresenter CreatePresenter()
        {
            Forms.Init();

            var xamarinFormsApp = new MvxFormsApp();
            return new MvxFormsIosPagePresenter(Window, xamarinFormsApp);
        }
```

However the MvxFormsApp class doesn't seem to exist anymore - and yes I have changed all the nuget dependances to the new ones

This is the error:
Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'MvxFormsApp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) (CS0246)

Comment: `are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?` tried adding the correct using directive?

Comment: Xamarin / Visual Studio for Mac couldn't resolve the reference at all. MVVMCross replied on Twitter that the class name has changed to MvxFormsApplication and the namespace it is in is MvvmCross.Forms.Core - so that has finally solved it. I have asked them to fix there migration instructions to give the correct class names and perhaps a note about the namespace

Comment: I am the one who replied using the MvvmCross account :) Strange that it couldn't resolve the using for you. Works fine in Visual Studio on Windows.

Comment: Oh cool :) Yeah - i find that sometimes Xamarin can resolve, and sometimes it can't. However it's not enough of a reason for me to go anywhere near windows again...

Answer (score 1):

MVVMCross replied on Twitter that the class name has changed to **MvxFormsApplication** and the namespace it is in is **MvvmCross.Forms.Core** - so that has finally solved it. I have asked them to fix their migration instructions to give the correct class names and perhaps a note about the namespace